# MySQL Multiple Joins from 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I need to select all records from assets_tbl (A). Included with these records I need to have any lightboxes (`lightbox_name`) that are linked to the 
`asset_id` from `assets_tbl` where `author = "scott@co.com"` OR `authorized_viewers` includes `"scott@co.com"`

I think this is close to what I need but it returns multiple rows of the same record:

```
SELECT
  A.*,
  C.lightbox_name,
  C.author,
  C.authorized_viewers
FROM
  media_tbl A
  LEFT JOIN lightbox_assets_tbl B ON A.asset_id = B.asset_id
  LEFT JOIN lightboxes_tbl C 
    ON B.lightbox_id = C.id
    AND C.author = "scott@co.com"
  LEFT JOIN lightboxes_tbl D ON D.authorized_viewers LIKE "scott@co.com"
ORDER BY A.id DESC
```

Here are the tables:

```
lightboxes_tbl
+-----+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
|id   |lightbox_name   |author         |authoried_viewers    |
+-----+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
|100  | aircraft-types |scott@co.com   |jon@co.com,aj@co.com |
|101  | maintenance    |nicole@co.com  |jon@co.com           |
|102  | ramp           |nicole@co.com  |scott@co.com         |
+-----+----------------+---------------+---------------------+



lightbox_assets_tbl
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
|id   |lightbox_id  |asset_name   |asset_path     | asset_id |
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
|1    |100          |a321.jpg     |project1/imgs/ | 3700     |
|2    |100          |b757.jpg     |project1/imgs/ | 3444     |
|3    |101          |FlyBy.swf    |project4/imgs/ | 1444     |
|4    |102          |Door_757.swf |project5/imgs/ | 3701     |
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+


assets_tbl
+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
|asset_id   |asset_name           | asset_location                |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
|3700       |a321.jpg             |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |
|200        |757_Taxi.swf         |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |
|3444       |b757.jpg             |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |
|1444       |FlyBy.swf            |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |
|3701       |Door_757.swf         |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |
+----------+---------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Here are the expected RESULTS of the query:

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|asset_id   |asset_name           | asset_location                |lightbox_name     | author      | authorized_viewers     |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|3700       |a321.jpg             |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |aircraft-types    |scott@co.com |jon@co.com,aj@co.com    |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|200        |757_Taxi.swf         |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |NULL              |NULL         |NULL                    |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|3444       |b757.jpg             |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |aircraft-types    |scott@co.com |jon@co.com,aj@co.com    |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|1444       |FlyBy.swf            |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |NULL              |NULL         |NULL                    |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|3701       |Door_757.swf         |Libraries\Library_Media\Images |ramp              |nicole@co.com|scott@co.com            |
+----------+---------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------------+
```

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/700b3b/3)

Thanks!

Comment: The "multiple rows per record" looks to be due to the `LEFT JOIN` on `D` -- there's nothing in that join's `ON` condition that relates it to the other tables, which results in a cartesian product.  That should be joining `lightbox_assets_tbl.lightbox_id`, no?

Comment: Proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) would have got you an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering why you need **two** joins to the `lightboxes_tbl` table. It seems like the second reference to that table (alias `D`) is unnecessary. Seems like you could just use an `OR`.

As a demonstration, replicating the predicates in your query:

```
LEFT JOIN lightboxes_tbl C
       ON B.lightbox_id = C.id
      AND ( C.author = 'scott@co.com'
          OR C.authorized_viewers = 'scott@co.com'
          )
```

But given that `authorized_user` contains a comma separated list (ACCKKK!!!), I suspect you really want to look for an exact match to an item in the comma separated list.  The `LIKE` comparison that currently have is equivalent to an equals comparison (to the entire contents of `authorized_viewers` column). You could add `'%'` wildcard characters to search for the value as part of the string...

But that approach is will also match strings containing e.g. `ebscott@co.com`, which may not be what you really want.

You could use the `FIND_IN_SET` function to find an exact match within the comma separated list...

```
LEFT JOIN lightboxes_tbl C
       ON B.lightbox_id = C.id
      AND ( C.author = 'scott@co.com'
          OR FIND_IN_SET('scott@co.com',C.authorized_viewers)
          )
```

---

Storing comma separated lists is a SQL anti-pattern. I recommend Bill Karwin's book: **SQL Anti-Patterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming**

[http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)